# HTML - move image if needed

Tags: html, image, ipad

I'm writing a small program on the iPad whose task is to display the contents of an html file. I use `document.documentElement.scrollHeight` (pageYOffset etc.) to paginate.

My problem is with images. Sometimes an image gets cut in half such that `50%` of the image is on page 1 the other `50%` is on page 2. How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649169/print-styles-how-to-ensure-image-doesnt-span-a-page-break <- This is basically the same problem. Not sure how well the `page-break` properties work on screen, though...

Comment: @peirix – They are ignored, as per spec. `page-break` doesn't apply to continuous media.

Comment: Hmm so how the other apps (readers) do this?

Comment: Why not use a script detection of an element like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scroling) ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not style your images with CSS and use a percentage value so that it scales to fit the screen?

You might also want to checkout Responsive Design.