# Print styles - prevent images from span over pages

Tags: css, image, printing

I'm currently making a website printer-friendly. Although I can't get it to work. Images and Columns are split over pages.

I tried adding:

```
img {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

I tried following this post:
[Print styles: How to ensure image doesn't span a page break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649169/print-styles-how-to-ensure-image-doesnt-span-a-page-break)

[image]

I want the images whole on the next page, if it does not fit on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Since You didn't Provide any codes It is harder for me to solve your problem properly.

page-break-inside has been deprecated and replaced by another method called **break-inside** (according to mozilla CDN)

[image: Image about page-break-inside deprecate]

try:

```
break-inside: avoid;
```

OR

```
break-inside: avoid-page;
```