# Print styles: How to ensure image span pages if there are texts above the image

Tags: javascript, css

I am currently working on an issue with printing from a browser. I have a relatively large image with some descriptive text on top of it, and I want to ensure that when printing, the image appears at the bottom of the page and get split. Because the size of the image is too large, it will automatically flow to the next page, causing a lot of blank space below the text.

What I'd like

```
Page 1 |                    |
       |  (text text text)  |
       |  (text text text)  |
       |  ________________  |
       | | Top of image   | |
       |____________________|
       ------page break------
        ____________________
Page 2 | | Rest of image  | |
       | |________________| |
       |         …          |
```

What I see now

```
Page 1 |                    |
       |  (text text text)  |
       |  (text text text)  |
       |                    |
       |                    |
       |                    |
       |                    |
       |                    |
       |                    |
       |____________________|
       ------page break------
        ____________________
Page 2 | |                | |
       | |                | |
       | |     image      | |
       | |                | |
       | |----------------| |
               ....
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print styles: How to ensure image doesn't span a page break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649169/print-styles-how-to-ensure-image-doesnt-span-a-page-break)