# Why can't I print a web page accurately?

Tags: css, html, printing

Given the following HTML code, why is it that when this document is printed in different browsers you get completely different results? All I want is to be able to generate a "page" from a javascript web-app that prints to a known scale! Seems pretty simple, but so far has been almost impossible to achieve.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="210mm" height="297mm"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2">

        <rect x="300" y="300" width="1in" height="1in" fill="red"/>
        <text x="100" y="100" font-size="1in">Hello</text>

    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you comment on how differently they come out? I could imagine a difference of +/- 10 or so pixels. The first reply: http://www.coderanch.com/t/131257/gc/Relation-between-pixel-cm-mm may provide more insight.

Comment: They print out at either 1" exactly, or about 1.15" or 0.9" depending on the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different Browser may differ when applying styles for printing.

If you want to have a consistent result across browsers, define your own print-styles.

Like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

*edit:* Some links on how to achieve good printing results:

[What are most useful media="print" specfic ,cross browser compatible css properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226939/what-are-most-useful-media-print-specfic-cross-browser-compatible-css-propert)
-> Link to A List Apart which normally has very good articles

[How to get cross browser compatibility in Print on page from all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697444/how-to-get-cross-browser-compatibility-in-print-on-page-from-all-browsers)

Comment: Fantastic insight there Christoph (and Pier!), I had no idea... I'll give this a go now though, hopefully this will be the answer to my printing-prayers! lol. As I simply want to remove any styles they may or may-not add, is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure that anything I've seen in the *.css will help with printing out the above consistently; I can see how it could be used with a highly complex web page, allowing you to change fonts / sizes / background colors / etc. However with this particular example I can't see how it can make the SVG stay consistent.

Comment: @Siyfion you can define css-styles for your SVG, which are then being applied when printing. Additionally it might help, if you define the viewPox of your svg.

Comment: Thanks again, the lack of a viewBox may well have been adding to the issues we were encountering!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to create a different style for the printing, depending of your browser. (`media="print"` in your css declaration)

Take a look here:

http://www.css-help.com/css-mediaprint.htm

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html